# Write to a file in React

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I am working on a React app that will run in Chrome in kiosk mode on a medical-grade tablet not connected to the internet. When I hit a certain button in the app, I need a simple small text file to be written to the device.

`File` API seems to be more for reading.

How can I accomplish this?

Update: I've tried `BrowserFS`, following the webpack config instructions and using the following code:

```js
const BrowserFS = require('browserfs');

export function write(text) {
  BrowserFS.install(window);

  BrowserFS.configure({ fs: "LocalStorage" }, e => {
    const fs = BrowserFS.BFSRequire('fs');
    fs.writeFile('/message.txt', text);
    fs.readdir('/', (e, contents) => {
      console.log(contents);
    });
  });

}
```

In my Chrome console it prints out `[message.txt]` so it looks like it's writing...but I can't find the file anywhere!

I've looked in `~/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Local Storage/` but it's not in there (not in `leveldb` below it).

Comment: I don't think this is possible without at least a little bit of user interaction.  A user would have to at least confirm saving the file to the actual system.  You can use the FileSystem API to persist data over the course of your app, but to actually export it out to the host system, you would need a confirm.  Consider the example that Google goes over in their [app tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab_filesystem).

Comment: I've looked at these tutorials but I'm not able to get to any of the properties of the `chrome` object.

Comment: Are you writing this in a webpage or as a WebExtension?

Comment: In a web app directly.